# perform calculations on multiple users-own records in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I need help extending a functional update query that performs calculations on one record to be able to perform calculations not only on one record in the database, but on all records associated with a particular user #.

Functionally, I need to extend an "edit this record" to "reevaluate all records of user#?"

Current calculations make use of 3 tables, sum a column, divide by the sum of another, and then creates a variable from that result(there are two columns summed separately to create two variables). Then I have a simple UPDATE query to update the record with the values of those variables.  Each record has different values, and the sums will be different for every id#
@lastid is the unique record id.(allinfsds.id1)
I need to have the calculations done on all records that = a particular owners id (allinfsds.own_id)[i.e. WHERE allinfsds.own_id= *usernum*]

Any ideas???
Thanks ahead of time, 
Nat

```
    CREATE TABLE `allingred` (
  `id6` int(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `usernum` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `fsdsnum` int(8) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `mfdfsds` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `maybe` decimal(2,1) NOT NULL default '1.0',
  `amount` float(10,2) default NULL,
  `unit` int(6) default NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `wgt` int(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id6`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=38 ;

    CREATE TABLE `weight` (
  `NDB_No2` int(8) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `Seq` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `amt2` decimal(5,3) NOT NULL,
  `Msre_Desc` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `Gm_Wgt` decimal(7,1) NOT NULL,
  `Num_Data_Pts` tinyint(4) default NULL,
  `Std_Dev` decimal(7,1) default NULL,
  `uni` int(7) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`uni`),
  KEY `fb_join_NDB_No2_INDEX` (`NDB_No2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=21731 ;

    CREATE TABLE `allinnot2` (
  `NDB_No` int(8) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `Water` decimal(10,2) default NULL,
  `Energ_Kcal` decimal(10,0) default NULL

    CREATE TABLE `allinfsds` (
  `id1` int(8) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `own_id` int(11) NOT NULL
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id1`),
  KEY `fb_groupbyorder_item_number_INDEX` (`item_number`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


    SET @cal = (SELECT SUM( Energ_Kcal * allingred.amount * Gm_Wgt) / SUM( allingred.amount * Gm_Wgt ) AS nut100
FROM  `allingred` 
LEFT JOIN weight ON allingred.unit = weight.uni
LEFT JOIN allinnot2 ON allingred.mfdfsds = allinnot2.NDB_No
LEFT JOIN allinfsds ON allingred.fsdsnum = allinfsds.own_id
WHERE fsdsnum = @lastid)

SET @prot = (SELECT SUM(Protein * allingred.amount * Gm_Wgt) / SUM( allingred.amount * Gm_Wgt ) AS nut100
FROM  `allingred` 
LEFT JOIN weight ON allingred.unit = weight.uni
LEFT JOIN allinnot2 ON allingred.mfdfsds = allinnot2.NDB_No
WHERE fsdsnum = @lastid)

UPDATE `allinnot2` SET
  `Energ_Kcal` = @cal,
  `Protein` = @prot
WHERE `NDB_No` = @lastid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to update multiple tuples at once**

If you have a list of Ids you want to update, use

```
UPDATE `myTable` SET `myColumn` = 'newValue' 
WHERE `userId` IN (
    /*list of relevant Ids for instance: */ 15, 20, 63, 987
)
```

or if you dont have this list, but you can query the database for this list, use

```
UPDATE `myTable` SET `myColumn` = 'newValue' 
WHERE `userId` IN (
    SELECT `userId` FROM `myOtherTable` WHERE `relevantColumn` = 'value'
)
```

Beware that you are not allowed to use the same table as both the update target and source of ids in the subselect, so `myTable` != `myOtherTable`.

Comment: ah, i see, my question is unclear.  in my query above, when i said 'WHERE fsdsnum = @lastid', i'm not referencing userids, but row ids, which there are many of for each userid.  so, what i currently do is select one row id A, which has a one to many relationship with other records(say 1,2,4,5), do a calculation on the sum of those related records, and then insert that value into row id A.   What I need to do is to do that same operation on all records, (say A,C,R,Z,X) that  belong to a particular userid(WHERE USER ID IN '546'), but separately.

Comment: nevermind, i get confused, your answer is clear and I am learning a lot!!  I modified my query to be this:   UPDATE aallinnot2 c SET c.Energ_Kcal = ( SELECT SUM( c.Energ_Kcal) 
    FROM aaingred a
    LEFT JOIN aaweight b ON a.unit = b.uni
    LEFT JOIN aallinnot2 c ON a.mfdfsds = c.NDB_No
    LEFT JOIN aalinfsds d ON a.fsdsnum = d.id1
    WHERE d.own_id =42
    GROUP BY id1 ) 
    WHERE c.NDB_No
    IN (    SELECT DISTINCT  `fsdsnum` 
    FROM  `aaingred` 
    WHERE  `usernum` LIKE  '42'
    )  but I get an error "#1093 - You can't specify target table 'c' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: Yes you can not select things from the table you are updating. You can use a [temporary table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) for this.